# Could the British policy of sending asylum seekers to Rwanda be described as "extraordinary rendition"?

Tags: terminology, immigration, asylum

The term "extraordinary rendition" entered the language a few years ago to describe the practice of enforcing, without legal process, the removal of people from one jurisdiction to another, when the US did it to so-called "suspected terrorists".

Is the term wide enough to describe what the British government is now attempting to do by sending illegal migrants, against their will, to Rwanda?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137282/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-could-the-british-policy-of-sending-asylum-seekers).

Answer (score 11):

If "extraordinary rendition" does mean "the practice of enforcing, without legal process, the removal of detained individuals from one jurisdiction to another" then no, the removals to Rwanda are not "extraordinary rendition".

Because, whatever one thinks of the policy, there is a legal process, there is statute providing for the process, and some removals have been halted by the courts.

(Incidentally extraordinary rendition was part of a larger program that involved indefinite detention in 'black-sites', torture and murder.)

Comment: I have downvoted, for the reason that we really have little knowledge about what leaving people in Rwanda will amount to. For all we know it could involve "black sites, torture and murder". The government has not given any indication how, if at all, the welfare of such abandonees will be monitored.

Comment: @WS2 This is beginning to look like a push question with you fishing for a certain answer.

Comment: @WS2 page 14 of the Commons Library Research Briefing "UK-Rwanda Migration and Economic Development Partnership" contains a section about the "Monitoring and oversight of MoU implementation".  https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-9568/CBP-9568.pdf

Comment: @WS2 Ultimately the removal can be described as rendition but not _extraordinary_ rendition, because by definition extraordinary rendition is done outside the law and these removals are not.

Comment: @Lag We will not know whether that be the case until the UK courts complete their judicial review towards the end of July. For the time being the ECHR has intervened and prevented a flight taking place. Last week they attempted to strong-arm people on to an aeroplane without full judicial approval. It sounds a pretty "extraordinary" thing for a British government to be doing - in my book.

Comment: @WS2 "For the time being the ECHR has intervened and prevented a flight taking place." - so there was a legal ruling and the the UK gov obeyed it? But nevertheless you seem to think that is equivalent to what we know of as "extraordinary rendition", which you yourself defined as "the practice of enforcing, _without legal process_, the removal ..." (my emphasis). Because you are playing with "extraordinary" and pushing your view as opposed to asking in good faith?

Comment: @Lag "Extraordinary" is a gradable adjective and there are degrees of extraordinariness.

Comment: "the removal can be described as rendition but not extraordinary rendition": part of the problem with this question, indeed most of it, is that there isn't an agreed or assumed definition of "extraordinary rendition." (@WS2 perhaps you can address this.) In particular, I read the mention of terrorists in the question as an example (or _the_ example) of people subjected to ER; that should not imply that terrorism is a defining element of ER, but some here are saying "it's not ER because these people aren't terrorists," which is not particularly useful.

Comment: I made a small edit because I downvoted this question after misreading it, thinking that it based its conclusion on the fact that terrorism was not involved.  Reading it again, I realized that I was wrong, and I wanted to change my vote, but I couldn't do so without the answer being edited.

Comment: @phoog Re definition, I tried to answer according to what I perceived to be the essential part of the definition in the question: "the practice of enforcing, without legal process, the removal ... " - but in retrospect my answer wasn't wholly clear.

Answer (score 2):

You are free to use (or misuse) terms as you like. Consider the Russian government defining the ongoing war in Ukraine as a "special miltiary operation". However, you may not always find it easy to get an audience to agree with you.

As a point of reference, the term "rendition" has certainly been used by commentators on [Australia's policy of offshore processing](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/oct/17/flying-a-refugee-to-nauru-in-secret-is-this-any-different-to-extraordinary-rendition) of assylum seekers. In detail, these pieces have tended to be intentionally somewhat hyperbolic, but have drawn analogy with the CIA's techniques, as well as pointing out the similarities.

Overall, if you choose to use the metaphor, you should recognise that it is not a one-to-one correspondence, that there are gradations in the deplorable, and that you run the risk of alienating your audience to your potential underlying message.

Comment: From the sound of that guardian article, the AUS *policy* would be "rendition", with the *practice* having instances where it was "extraordinary", e.g. the alleged secret flight bypassing a court.